# Apache Server discards requests but application gets 200 as response

Tags: android, apache, http-post, httpresponse

I have an apache server that gets POST requests from an Android device for further process. 
First the user has to log in. Then the server returns a cookie that the app uses to detect if the credentials are valid. Then the user can send requests to the server.
Because the mobile device may experience 3G/4G network issues I check after sending every request the response code that the server returns. If the response code is not 200 I save the request data and try again after some time.

The strange part of this process is that sometimes (randomly) although I get 200 as response the server rejects the data get lost. Even stranger is that when I tried to read the log file.. (It's pretty big because the server hosts more than one projects) i saw that the server logged that responded with 302 instead of 200 that i get on my device...

I wrote a php script that returns 302 as response and I tested my Android application and runs fine. It detects that response is not 200 and saves the data correctly. I also tried to send data to the server without log in and I get 302 as it should.

So I suspect that the problem is on the server side. What can I do? I am trying to figure out what's wrong for about six months but it happens randomly and i cannot find the cause. Has anybody faced the same problem in the past?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

So, I finally found the bug. For some reason the session expired and I redirected back to the login page thats why 302 logged, and after the successful load of the login page I got 200. I forced apache client to prevent redirects and its fine now